# Copying and transposing from one workbook to another - 'Run time error 1004'

Tags: vba, copy, runtime-error, transpose

I am attempting to copy and transpose data from one workbook to another using the following but i get a Run Time Error 1004. Could anyone please help with how to resolve this issue. It appears to be in this section of code:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
   , Transpose:=True
```

I am unsure how to resolve.

See below for full code:

```
Windows("ETP2016_scenario_summary (2).xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:H7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
       , Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(12, 1).Range("A1:H13").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 19
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 26
    ActiveCell.Offset(16, 0).Range("A1:H8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-4, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 40
    ActiveCell.Offset(11, 0).Range("A1:H8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-3, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 44
    ActiveCell.Offset(17, 1).Range("A1:H6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-5, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 62
    ActiveCell.Offset(9, 0).Range("A1:H8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 68
    ActiveCell.Offset(13, 1).Range("A1:H8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 79
    ActiveCell.Offset(11, 0).Range("A1:H8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 90
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 97
    ActiveCell.Offset(11, 0).Range("A1:H16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 113
    ActiveCell.Offset(19, 0).Range("A1:H16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-6, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
        , Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first Paste, where are you pasting it to? you need to select a `Range` first

Answer (score 1):

Your first **Paste** using **Transpose** you didn't select a destination Range to Paste it to.

Replace your:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
   , Transpose:=True
```

With:

```
 ' replace Sheet2 with your Sheet Name, Modify Range("A1) to your Range
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help Shai. I still cannot get it to work and get a runt time error 9 when i replace the code. I am transposing it to another workbook. How do i input the workbook that it is to be copied to into the code? And alos, if i want to copy and transpose into cells B3:H10 is this the range i should input?

Comment: @Matt what is the name of your other workbook ? what is the name of the worksheet in that workbook you are trying to copy to